# maven dependency is not available in classpath while running java -jar command

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have built a jar using maven and build was successful.
When I am trying to run this jar using `java -jar` a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception is coming as all maven dependency jars are not available in classpath.

My pom.xml is as following-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pdss-loadTesting</groupId>
<artifactId>load-testing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>pdss_load_testing</name>
<description>load test pdss</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>loadtesting.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-java-slice</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <exec executable="mkdir">
                                <arg value="-p" />
                                <arg value="target/generated-sources" />
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="git">
                                <arg value="submodule" />
                                <arg value="init" />
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="git">
                                <arg value="submodule" />
                                <arg value="update" />
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="git">
                                <arg value="submodule" />
                                <arg value="foreach" />
                                <arg value="git" />
                                <arg value="checkout" />
                                <arg value="master" />
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="git">
                                <arg value="submodule" />
                                <arg value="foreach" />
                                <arg value="git" />
                                <arg value="pull" />
                                <arg value="origin" />
                                <arg value="master" />
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="slice2java">
                                <arg value="-I/usr/share/Ice-3.4.2/slice" />
                                <arg value="submodules/slice/asr/asr.ice" />
                                <arg value="submodules/slice/pds/pds.ice" />
                                <arg value="--underscore" />
                                <arg value="--output-dir" />
                                <arg value="target/generated-sources" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extracted</outputDirectory>
                        <includeTypes>zip</includeTypes>
                        <includeClassifiers>include</includeClassifiers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <!--version>2.3.1</version> <configuration> <source>1.5</source> <target>1.5</target> 
                </configuration -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.8.1</version> <configuration> <show>private</show> <nohelp>true</nohelp> 
            </configuration> <executions> <execution> <id>attach-javadocs</id> <goals> 
            <goal>jar</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.samsung.sec.svoice.asr.dash.DashAsrWrapper</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly-jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            generate-sources
                                        </goal>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-dependency-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            unpack-dependencies
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        aspectj-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.3,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<!-- add dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId> <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1.5</version> </dependency -->
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.mockito</groupId> <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId> 
        <version>1.9.5</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.3</version> </dependency -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> 
        <version>1.7.2</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency> <groupId>Ice</groupId> <artifactId>zeroc-ice</artifactId> 
        <version>3.4.2</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zeroc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ice</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.samsung.svoice</groupId>
        <artifactId>registry-framework</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.samsung.svoice</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdss_prashant</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>Ice</groupId>
        <artifactId>zeroc-ice</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/Ice.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <!-- Publish the releases here -->
    <repository>
        <id>dcog</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/repositories/dcog
                    </url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Publish snapshots here -->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>dcog-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/repositories/dcog-snapshots
                    </url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<!-- download artifacts from this repo -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>public</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>svoice</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/repositories/svoice/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>svoice-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/repositories/svoice-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!--repository> <id>sonatype</id> <name>Sonatype Groups</name> <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url> 
        </repository -->
</repositories>

<!-- download plugins from this repo -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>public</id>
        <url>https://maven.samsungcloud.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
                    </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: what command are you using to run your jar? or are you running it through eclipse?

Comment: Os - linux (centos 6)

Comment: i am using "java -jar" buy command line, i am not using eclipse

Comment: You are using maven assembly plugin there so I assume you want to package your jar as a executable jar with all dependencies. Is that right? You mention "<descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>" in the assembly plugin. Could you share the assembly.xml here?

Comment: @htulsiani yes i am creating an executable jar.